# Is the pytorch_transformers from huggingface maintained?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

Huggingface has two libraries **Pytorch_transformers 1.2.0 and transformers 4.** and others? There are some papers using the code from **pytorch_transformers** and I am trying to implement some production based solutions on **pytorch_transformers**? Are the **huggingface** maintaining the "**pytorch_transformers**" library?

Comment: Last release 4th of September 2019 ([link](https://pypi.org/project/pytorch-transformers/#history). Better work with the transformers library directly. It has plenty of new features.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on [discuss.huggingface.co](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/pytorch-transformers-vs-transformers/1484/2)

> pytorch_transformers was older name/version. It later got renamed to transformers after adding support for TF. [...]

So the answer is *yes*, under a new name.

Comment: @Prem I guess that you will have to ask (in another SO question) for the transformers4 version of the code you have found, (providing us with the names of the papers may help) if you want to deal with an actively maintained library. This is almost an opinion-based comment but: to me, implying pytorch_transformers as such in production is a non-starter indeed. Any question otherwise ?